# How to sort Fiscal month that are stored as Nvarchar in SQL server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have stored Fiscal month as a Nvarchar column in a table and want to sort that table based on fiscal month.

Create Table sample(
            id Ineger
            ,FiscalMonth Nvarchar(MAX)
);

Ex: Table contain this data

```
Id   FiscalMonth
-----------------
1     FY15-Oct
2     FY15-Sep
3     FY15-Jul
4     FY15-Aug
```

Now if i sort this table on order by FiscalMonth Column Result would be:
SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY FiscalMonth;

Result:

```
Id   FiscalMonth
-----------------
4     FY15-Aug
3     FY15-Jul
1     FY15-Oct
2     FY15-Sep
```

But i want result as

Expected Output:

```
Id   FiscalMonth
-----------------
3     FY15-Jul
4     FY15-Aug
2     FY15-Sep
1     FY15-Oct
```

Can somebody help me how to approach on this problem without changing the schema of table?

Comment: Can't you spend the time to fix this issue instead to fix the design flaw? Either store it as `date`/`datetime` or in two columns `year` and `month`. Formatting doesn't belong into the database.

Comment: Is this mysql or mssql server? As you have conflicting tags?

Comment: All of the answers are irrelevant until we know the DBMS. The question states his table contains NVARCHAR(MAX). This does not exist in MySQL...so the answers using MySQL may be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to sort for different years and then by month the `order by` in MS SQL should work as below:

```
SELECT [Id],[FiscalMonth]
From Sample
order by convert(date,Substring([FiscalMonth],6,3)+ ' 01 ' + Substring([FiscalMonth],3,2),103)
```

This assumes that your `FiscalMonth` Column is always the same format.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a number for each month, distinguish them you can for the last three letter.

```
SUBSTRING (FiscalMonth , 5 , 3 )
```

And after that sorted by those numbers.

Comment: What about the year? 2014 DEC should be before 2015 APR

Comment: Ok, you can build a date by DATEADD function. Read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in MYSQL

```
SELECT   myDate
FROM     myTest
ORDER BY
  LEFT(myDate,2),
  CAST(MID(myDate,2) AS UNSIGNED),
  MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(myDate,3),'%b'))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7766/7)**

or simply

```
SELECT   myDate
FROM     myTest
ORDER BY
  MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(myDate,3),'%b'))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7766/8)**

You need to convert the three letter into the number i.e, Jan-1, Feb-2, Mar-3 and so on and then you can use the order by to it.

(*Same logic can be applied in SQL Server as well  i.e, take the last three charaters ie, month name and convert it into number and then use order by*)

**On a side note:**

It would be a good idea to create the column as date time and then you can store the value and use the datetime function to get this done easily.

Comment: That may work. But If you encapsulate it in a function you will be able to reuse it and the name will show the purpose.

Comment: @borjab:- Yes true. I just tried to give the clue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just two steps:

- Create a database fuction that returns the date of the first day of the fiscal month.  fnGetFiscalFirstDay('FY15-Jul')  ->  01 Jul 2015
- Sort by the function:

  SELECT *
   FROM sample s
  ORDER BY fnGetFiscalFirstDay(s.FiscalMonth)